# Content theft prevention (webscraping) via CSS

Tags: firefox, css

I'm here because I got: *You must have at least 5 reputation on Super User to ask a question on meta, but you may ask a question about your own Super User post specifically.* Alrighty then!

I like to write and give away that content. But what happens is that someone, typically from outside the US, will copy my writing and then actually publish it as their own, even making e-books and selling them. Yep, outright plagiarism theft. But it's improbable to catch them, or do anything about it even if you know exactly who it is/was. I have the following choices: forget posting anything on any web-page, and just publish it all via e-books (and POD paper), which means people would have to pay to read (Amazon and others will not give away anything; I've checked already). Or, continue to get robbed. Or, and what I'm hoping to do: Find a CSS (or ??) way to offer it free to read online, but impossible to copy or otherwise steal. Now of course, I've done the CSS/HTML:

Body {-webkit-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none; } (CSS)

body oncontextmenu='return false;' onkeydown='return false;' onmousedown='return false;' (HTML)

But with Firefox & other browsers with the Reader View function, it's easy to circumvent that and easily copy the content anyway. Must I stop publishing for free online? I know, everyone thinks everything online should be free: That's what I'm doing! Don't need that lecture, just tech advise if there is any, to prevent the plagiarism & theft. Thanx!

Comment: And, now you have a reputation of 6. Of course, you could publish in ePUB and publish it through free publishing sites such as Project Guttenberg https://www.gutenberg.org/ among others https://www.tckpublishing.com/websites-download-ebooks/ You may also find https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/ a useful resource.

Comment: *[Make content] impossible to copy or otherwise steal.* -- This is simply unrealistic, unfortunately(?). People who are dedicated to redistributing your content in a manner you disapprove of will almost always find a way to do so.

Comment: You can't do this at all.  At minimum, you have to send the content to readers, and they can just read and manually transcribe it, and there's absolutely no way you can prevent that.